# Creating Multiple ImageButtons in a Single Activity Programatically

Tags: android

I have a single image `myimage.png` which is placed in my `res`-`drawable` folder.
I have to create 50 ImageButtons in an activity all using this same image.

And then when a user clicks i need to pop out a toast saying button number i was clicked.

Here's what I have done:

```
public class AllImageButtons extends Activity {

int screendimesionx;
int screendimesiony;
ImageButton imageButton;
ImageButton allImageButtons[] = new ImageButton[50];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.allbuttonimages);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screendimesiony = metrics.heightPixels;
    screendimesionx = metrics.widthPixels;

    createButtonsAndAddListener();

}



public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        float buttonimagey = imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().height();
        float buttonimagex = imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
        float xspaceforeachbuttonimage = screendimesionx/50;
        LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams)imageButton.getLayoutParams();
        par.leftMargin = (int) (i*xspaceforeachbuttonimage);
        par.topMargin = 0;
        imageButton.setLayoutParams(par);
        allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
        allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(AllbuttonimagesForSelectionActivity.this,
                        "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }


        });

    }
}}
```

and then there is the associated xml file  `allbuttonimages.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This xml layout displays only the last ImageButton from the loop.

**My Question:**

How can i dynamically create all 50 ImageButtons from the same image in a single view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one button in layout and you are calling findViewById for that.

You need to create new buttons each time and add it to the linearlayout.

```
public void createButtonsAndAddListener() {

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
    float buttonimagey = imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().height();
    float buttonimagex = imageButton.getDrawable().getBounds().width();
    float xspaceforeachbuttonimage = screendimesionx/50;
    LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams)imageButton.getLayoutParams();
    par.leftMargin = (int) (i*xspaceforeachbuttonimage);
    par.topMargin = 0;
    imageButton.setLayoutParams(par);
    allImageButtons[i] = imageButton;
    allImageButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(AllbuttonimagesForSelectionActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }


    });
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll)).addView(imageButton);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/ll">    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how does imageButton = new ImageButton(this); refer to 'myimage'   in the drawable folder ?

Comment: you need to set image resource as well

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the buttons to the parent .
use `addView(yourImageButton)` to add your image button to activity

The button that is visible now is the one in xml

You should create new imageButton using `new`

eg: `ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(this)`
Then set the properties and `addView` to your parent Layout

You will not get 50 buttons with the one defined in xml

Answer (score 1):

Your code wont add images to the layout. Get the parent layout in code and add images to it using addView. Between you do not need the image button in the xml. You can do some thing like this:

```
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.the_parent_layout);
    for(int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton(context);
        //set whatever properties you want

       //then add to the parent
       parent.addView(image); // you can also specify the layout params here  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This....

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(myrefmenu);
    b1.setId(100 + i);
    b1.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
   // b1.setText(adapt_objmenu.city_name_array[i]);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (i > 0) {
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, b1.getId() - 1);
    }   
     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Toast.makeText(AllbuttonimagesForSelectionActivity.this,
                    "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    b1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    relative.addView(b1);
}
```